# Shell script - loop through values in multiple columns of a csv file

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk

I am working with a huge CSV file (`filename.csv`) that contains two columns. From column 1, I wanted to read current row and compare it with the value of the previous row. If it is `greater` OR `equal`, continue comparing and if the value of the current cell is `smaller` than the previous row - then i wanted to jump to the second column and take the value in the current row (of the second column). Next I wanted to divided the value `larger value` we got in column 1 by the value in the same cell of column two. For example in the following table: the smaller value we will get depending on my requirement is 327 (because 327 is smaller than the previous value 340) - and then we take 500 (which is the corresponding cell value on column two). Finally we divide 340 by 500 and get the value 0.68. My bash script should exit right after we print the value to the console.

```
338  800
338  550
339  670
340  600 
327  500
301  430
299  350
284  339
284  338
283  335
283  330
283  310
282  310
282  300
282  300
283  290
```

In the following script, it works only for column 1 but i want to extend it for two columns based on my criteria i mentioned above.

```
awk '$1<p{ 
    val=$1/p                   
    if(val>=0.8 && val<=0.9)
        {
            print "value is:" $1/p
            print "A"
        }
    else if(val==0.8)
        {
            print "B"
        }
    else if(val>=0.6 && val <=0.7)
        {
            print "C" 

        }
    else if(val==0.5)
        {
            print "E"
        }
    else
        {
            print "D" 
        }
    exit
    }
    { 
        p=$1 
    }' filetest.csv
```

How can we loop through the values in two columns and perform control statement?

PS: the criteria for my if-else statement is (if the value is >=0.8 and <=0.9, print A, else if the value) is >=0.7 and <=0.8, print B, if the value is >=0.5 and <=0.7 print C otherwise print D).

Comment: your first expected value `0.654` is bigger than `0.65`, that's why it doesn't fit any of your conditions

Comment: actually the values doesn't matter - i will fix that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first expected value `0.654` is bigger than `0.65`(the 3rd condition as the closest one), that's why it doesn't fit any of your conditions.

Extend your script as shown below:

```
awk '$1<p{ 
    val=$1/$2  # to divide the first column value on the second column value              
    if(val>=0.85 && val<=0.9)
        {
            print "value is:" $1/p
            print "A"
        }
    else if(val==0.8)
        {
            print "B"
        }
    else if(val>=0.5 && val <=0.7)
        {
            print "C" 

        }
    else if(val==0.5)
        {
            print "E"
        }
    else
        {
            print "D" 
        }
    exit
    }
    { 
        p=$1 
    }' filetest.csv
```

The output:

```
C
```

---

The crucial line I've modified is:

```
val=$1/$2  # to divide the first column value on the second column value
```

Comment: shouldn't the expression for "p" be changed (or modified)?

Comment: @Mahsolid, why should it? I have fixed your script according to your input description

Comment: oh, sorry. i got it now and thanks. Accepted answer!

Comment: by the way, when i try to run it - i got this error `awk: cmd. line:2: (FILENAME=filetest.csv FNR=23) fatal: division by zero attempted`

Comment: That could be. We can debug that moment. Let's print those values before the division: `print $1, $2; val=$1/$2`. What is the debug output?

Comment: It is actually printing only the last two digits of the first column numbers. `38,550
 27,500
 01,430
 99,350
 84,339
 84,338
 83,335
 83,330
 83,310
 82,310
 82,300`

Comment: there's no zero values within debug output. Try to replace the condition `$1<p` with `$1<p && $2!=0`

Comment: when we do print $1, it is taking only the last two digits

Comment: it's illogical. `print $1` prints the first field value

Comment: aha, i think the problem was probably it is because i was using "," instead of tab. I thought awk will recognize csv files.

Comment: @Mahsolid, nope, if comma is a separator you should specify `awk -F, `. Space is default field separator in AWK

Comment: thank you so much man. You are awesome. Have you seen my new requirement by the way? I have updated it a while ago.

Comment: @Mahsolid, sorry, but in such manner someone's can update his question 100 times, thus trying to obtain solutions on 100 different tasks. So, we can have same input but different tasks which we can divide into separate questions. You know what I mean ...

Comment: OK, I will ask a separate question then. thank you so much